# yocto: clamav recipe fails to find file in mirror

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe, clamav

I am working with yocto on zeus branch. I wanted to add an antivirus so I checked on ClamAV.

I added meta-security and the clamAV recipe to my system with the meta-security revision b66e5e27b48c0a07494f9df9b809ed933cede047 (http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/110195/)

When I run the build, the following error appears, so it seems that the clamav mirror does not have the path to the necessary file:

```
ClamAV update process started at Thu Feb  9 13:40:08 2023
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.99.4 Recommended version: 0.103.7
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
ERROR: getfile: Unknown response from database.clamav.net (IP: 104.16.218.84)
ERROR: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Giving up on database.clamav.net...
```

Is there a way to obtain the file I am missing or to specify another mirror?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried to change version ? In recipes-security/clamav/clamav_0.99.4.bb  change SRC_URI = "git://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel;branch=rel/0.99 \  to recommended version.

Answer (score 0):

That revision does not exist for some reason.

Create bbappend and try to use `b66e5e27b48c0a07494f9df9b809ed933cede047` which is the HEAD of the same branch.